# Implementing OAuth1 in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to set up NestJs with PassportJs for the Atlassian stack (Bamboo)
Unfortenly the Documentation only explains how to do it with local authentication.

I read the documentation and PassportJs for Nestjs should provide the Strategy which i use, but I'm getting the " OAuth authentication requires session support" error in NestJS.

So I tried to configure it in my auth.module.ts.

```js
import { HttpModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthController } from '../Controller/auth.controller';
import { AppService } from '../../app.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '../../config/config.module';
import { OAuth1 } from '../strategy/o-auth1.service';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule, ConfigModule, PassportModule.register({ session: true })],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AppService, OAuth1],
  exports: [PassportModule.register({ session: true })],
})

export class AuthModule {
}
```

This would be the Module

```js
import { ConfigService } from '../../config/config.service';
import { Injectable, Req, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-atlassian-oauth';
import { ExpressSessionMiddleware } from '@nest-middlewares/express-session';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class OAuth1 extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'oauth1') {
  constructor(private readonly envConfig: ConfigService) {
    super(
      {
        applicationURL: 'http://localhost:8085/',
        consumerKey: consumerkey,
        consumerSecret: consumerSecret,
        callbackURL: envConfig.thisCallbackURL,
      },
      (token, tokenSecret, profile, cb) => {
        User.findOrCreate({ exampleId: profile.id }, (err, user) => {
          return cb(err, user);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This the Implemented strategy

```js
@Get('')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('oauth1'))
  async auth(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response): Promise<string> {
    console.log(this);
    try {
      console.log('');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    res.send('hallo');
    return 'test';
  }
```

This the controller

I tried to play around, but i cant find any solution

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your main.ts

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import session = require('express-session');

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.use(session({ secret: 'you secret', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true }));
  await app.listen(3010);
}

bootstrap();
```

Comment: Hi @kira, I tried to follow your answer and question, but it doesn't work, I don't know how to work it out in nestjs.Can you please clarify who is the controller or service that handles `callbackURL: envConfig.thisCallbackURL`?

Comment: I keep getting: `{"trace":"InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile\n    at \\node_modules\\passport-atlassian-oauth\\lib\\passport-atlassian-oauth\\strategy.js:95:33\n`, I am trying your solution on Jira

Comment: Hi @Adham Sabry it's a while ago. but envConfig is a service which loads my environment file and puts everything like key, id's and so on in the right object. I don't have access to this code, else I would share it. So my Callback url is in a file which is read by envConfig.thisCallbackURL